# turf js union with array of features

Tags: geojson, mapbox-gl-js, turf

I am using Mapbox GL JS and querying a source on a common ID.

```
var tempId= 55;

var relatedFeatures=map.querySourceFeatures('featureSource', {
    sourceLayer: "sourceLayerId",
    filter: ['in', "FID",tempId]
 });
```

This returns an array of geojson features. If I pass this directly to turf union like below it throws an error

```
turf.union(relatedFeatures)
```

I can iterate over the array like below and union the features together but this seems unnecessary. Any suggestion for doing this more efficiently?

```
var featuresJoined=relatedFeatures[1]
  if(relatedFeatures.length>1){
    $.each(relatedFeatures,function(i,item){
      if(i>1){
        featuresJoined=turf.union(featuresJoined,item)                      
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're yet in TurfJS version 6, the spread operator `...` does not work because as [docs](http://turfjs.org/docs/#union) mention, `turf.union` only accepts two parameters `turf.union(poly1, poly2)`

A workaround is to use `Array.prototype.reduce`, but it is CPU intensive

```js
const polygons = [poly1, poly2, poly3, ..., polyn]
const union = polygons.reduce((a, b) => turf.union(a, b), polygons[0])
```

In version 7 (not yet published by the time of writing) you would be able then to use the spread operator combined with `featureCollection`

```js
const polygons = [poly1, poly2, poly3, ..., polyn]
var union = turf.union(turf.featureCollection(...polygons));
```

In both previous examples `poly[n]` are GeoJSONs JS Objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your array of features as an argument list (see e.g.:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856069/8620332), so it would look sth like this:

```
var featuresJoined = turf.union.apply(this, relatedFeatures);
```

Comment: It's better to add links as a hyperlink in answers or questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach of iterating over each feature is a valid approach.

According to http://turfjs.org/docs/#union `union` doesn't accept an array of features instead each feature must be an argument to `union`, so if you're targeting ES6 you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
turf.union(...relatedFeatures)
```

Otherwise Magnus's answer should also work.

Comment: Just to clarify - You can merge two OR MORE polygons at a time. Your wording says different from the docs.

Comment: Thanks @geofu I've updated the answer to mentioned spread syntax.

Comment: This seems wrong, the documentation has been [updated](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/pull/1285) on turf/union, which accepts **only** two polygons.

Comment: This is still wrong btw.